# Will a raspbian SD card work interchangeably between RPi units?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I made surveillance webcam for my parents using the Raspberry Pi, but they managed to break the SD slot somehow. Will a new RPi paired with the (working) SD card from the previous build work out of the box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the raspberry don t have any built in OS, just a bios, it work only from the SD card for all.

Since two RPi have the exact same specs, the only difference would be in software, whose will be the same since you are using the same SD card.

It s like pairing a working HDD on a other computer with exact same specs, it will work as it was on the original.

In the same way, if you want to test another RPi OS, you just have to put it on another SD card, and put it in, it will work the same.